# observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded) in FireBase doesnt refresh my view

Tags: swift, firebase, chat

Im trying to create a chat between two clients using firebase
first when entering the view Im downloading once the last 50 messages:
here the code:

```
current_room_id_url.queryLimitedToLast(50).queryOrderedByChild("date").observeSingleEventOfType(FEventType.Value) { (snapshot:FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in

            if let values = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                for item in values {
                    print(item)
                    if !self.keys.contains(snapshot.key){
                        self.keys.append(item.key as! String)

                        if let message = item.value as? NSDictionary{
                            let date = message["date"] as! NSTimeInterval
                            let receiveSenderID = message["senderId"] as! String
                            let displayName = message["senderDisplayName"] as! String
                            self.createAvatar(receiveSenderID, senderDisplayName: displayName, color: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor())
                            let jsqMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: receiveSenderID , senderDisplayName: displayName, date: NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: date), text: message["message"] as! String)
                            self.messages.append(jsqMessage)
                        }
                    }
                }
                //self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                self.messages.sortInPlace({ ($0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending)})
                self.finishReceivingMessageAnimated(true)
            }
        }
```

and after that I want to get all messages sent in RealTime: Im using that function:

```
 current_room_id_url.queryLimitedToLast(1).observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot:FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
        if !self.keys.contains(snapshot.key){
            self.keys.append(snapshot.key)
            if let message = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                let date = message["date"] as! NSTimeInterval
                let receiveSenderID = message["senderId"] as! String
                let receiveDisplayName = message["senderDisplayName"] as! String
                self.createAvatar(receiveSenderID, senderDisplayName: receiveDisplayName, color: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor())
                let jsqMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: receiveSenderID, senderDisplayName: receiveDisplayName, date: NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: date), text: message["message"] as! String)
                self.messages.append(jsqMessage)
                if receiveSenderID != self.senderId{
                    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageReceivedSound()
                }
            }
            self.finishReceivingMessageAnimated(true)
        }
    }
```

When I try to debug that with a debreakpoint I see that Im entering the second function only when Im getting out and entering back the view while obviously I need it to happen when I am in the chatRoom ...
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `.queryLimitedToLast(1)` if an added child will always be the last?

Comment: thanks Tim thats solve it !!